# Override the validate function django

Tags: python, django

In my forms.py
I have a class Taskform, this is a function in the class

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(TaskForm, self).clean()
    start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
    end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')
    if start_date and end_date:
        if start_date >= end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("'End date' must be after 'Start date'"))
    admin_time = cleaned_data.get('admin_time')
    if admin_time:
        cleaned_data['execution_time'] = admin_time
    return cleaned_data
```

What I am trying to do is- replace execution time by admin_time whenever admin_time is entered.

Models.py
I have execution_time defined like this:

```
execution_time = models.IntegerField(
    choices=((i, i) for i in (15, 30, 45, 60)),
    blank=False,
    default=30,
    verbose_name='estimated time'
```

What happens is, if I give a value that is there in the choices (15,30,45,60) to admin_time, the valid function runs. But if any other value is given for admin_time it gives invalid choice.

How to override the validate option and update the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method "validate" in "ChoiceField", without doing any checks in it for the presence on the list "choices" form element and do a basic check in the method of "clean" your form. In order to have access to the list of items in the "choices" are usually added at the level of the model attribute "CHOICES" which will be available on the "MyModel.CHOICES".